# Java NullPointerException trying to add to an ArrayList inside a class used as the value for a HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I'm trying to make a very basic software simulation of a router that reads in a text file and acts on the commands and other information given to it.  I made a new class called groupclass to hold an ArrayList

```
package router;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class groupclass 
{
    public ArrayList<String> member;
}
```

Made a HashMap with it as the value

```
static Map<Integer, groupclass> groupmap = new HashMap<Integer, groupclass>();
```

And tried this code

```
private static void groupadd(int groupnum, String address)
{
    out.println("debug groupadd");

    try
    {
        groupmap.get(groupnum).member.add(address);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        groupmap.put(groupnum, new groupclass());
        groupmap.get(groupnum).member.add(address);
    }
}
```

Which throws a NullPointerException at

```
groupmap.get(groupnum).member.add(address);
```

The idea was to make a map and associate a new groupclass object with each group number, and each groupclass would have a list of IPs stored as strings.  I'm at a complete loss here, and any tweaks I do cause weirder problems and build errors I don't understand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never initialize `member` in `groupclass`; it's `null`. What is the confusion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: Just a minor overlook.  I haven't used ArrayList before this code and didn't think about it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your member variable "member" is not initialized. Add

public member=new ArrayList<>();

Comment: minus the word `public` of course.  Or even `member = new ArrayList<String>();` if you don't have Java 7.

Comment: This is technically correct, however it is best practice to parametrize the `<` and `>` area with the data type (in the OP's condition, you would want to use `String` in the middle).